# ClickOnce Deployment multiple folders for each DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, clickonce

Everytime I deploy my ClickOnce application it creates a bunch of directories with a single dll inside it.

It doesn't even use them and I'm not sure how to disable their creation.

[Actual Directory http://imageshack.us/a/img818/6347/folderstructure.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img818/6347/folderstructure.png)

Each time I open it them it's just ONE dll in there.

[Actual Directory http://imageshack.us/a/img15/6027/directoryb.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img15/6027/directoryb.png)

This is the actual working directory.  I can delete the other folders manually, but I'm not sure what I need to do to make sure the clickonce deployment doesn't create the other directories.

[Actual Directory http://imageshack.us/a/img11/573/actualdirectory.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img11/573/actualdirectory.png)

Any idea on how to disable the Clickonce installer to not create the other directories?

Thanks,

Raff

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clean the list out by going through each project and modifying the assembly information so that it was not com enabled and all the fields filled. out.

Hopefully this will help anyone else that might find a similar issue.